# dojo how to find out the exact line of code which throw and exception when a module loaded with require is not found?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dojo and I need to find out the exact line of code which throw and exception when a module loaded with require is not found... At the moment I see in console src: dojoLoader.
In dojoConfig debug is true, could you please point me out in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you view the error in the console it should tell you the module which it is unable to find. It will be under the info object.

[image]

If you are wanting to find out which module is requiring it then just do a global search.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know from which file is calling the NOT found module, possibly even at which line... is it possible to have these information in console?

Comment: Well when you are defining a module all dependencies are on your first line so I don't think line number will make any difference. I have used dojo a lot and don't know of anyway other then `ctrl+f` there can't be many references to the missing module and either way you will need to change all of them as the path is invalid.

Comment: I am able to see error line in dojo framework but never the line of my custom code...

Comment: I understand your point with ctrl+f and at the moment I do the same, but definitely would be cool gather more precise errosr as require() could be called on user interaction and not only at module load.